# Is fql.multiquery still going to be supported in the future by facebook?

Tags: fql.multiquery

I am new to facebook app creation and I am using fql to get the data i need.
I came accross fql.multiquery but I see in facebook that it is part of the legacy rest api that is going to be discontinued soon.

Is this true?

If so then how else could I save on requests to the facebook api??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FQL whould not be deprecated. It simply migrates from REST API to Graph API. Use fql method of the Graph API, to access fql query and multi-query. You can read about this in the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).